# What is happening when a Constructor uses 1 argument, but base keyword uses 2 arguments

Tags: c#, overloading, base-class

I have this bit of code and it will demonstrate a Liskov substitution, but I'm confused what the base keyword is doing with 2 arguments. Can someone explain?

```
class Rectangle
{
    public Rectangle(int width, int height)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
    }
    public virtual int Height {get;set;}
    public virtual int Width {get;set;}
    public int Area
    {
        get { return Height*Width }
}
```

And now for the square class that inherits the base class with 2 arguments. I was also curious why this next Method Square(int) can use a method in the base class with a different name

```
private class Square : Rectangle
{
    public Square(int size) : base(size, size) {} ///here is my confusion
    public override int Width
    {
        get {return base.Width}
        set { base.Width = value; base.Height = value}
    }
    public override int Height
    { /// same thing as Width }
}
```

Comment: Its calling the parent constructor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`base(size, size)` calls the parent constructor ( Rectangle's in this case ), this constructor takes 2 arguments, that's why size is specified twice.

Because a square must have the same height and width the size parameter can be used for both `width` and `height`

Comment: So If I pass 1 value into Square(5). Does it set the Height and Width in the base case?

Comment: @christopherclark Yes, it does. `Square(5)` will call `Rectangle(5, 5)` which will set the `height` and `width` members to `5`